# importing chopped data in r

Tags: r, import

Here is a segment of my data. When i do read.csv(data, sep = " ") i get a dataframe with columns and rows. However this data is all of one type, so i just need either one row, one column or a vector.

Any help is apreciated.

```
0 0 0 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 40 40 40 40 40 40 50 50 50 50 50 50 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60 60  60 60 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 70 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 90 90 90 90 90  90 90 90 90 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 110 110 110 110 110 110  110 110 110 110 110 110 120 120 120 120 120 130 130 130 130 130 130 140  140 140 140 140 140 140 140 150 150 150
```

Comment: Try `?scan` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about:

`scan(data,what="numeric", sep=" ")`

When you use ´read.csv´ (or any read.xxx) R understand that you're trying to import a table, so it creates a dataframe with columns and rows with the contents of the file. You can read as a string directly with `scan` or change the dataframe later:

Load the data:

`df=read.csv(data, sep=" ")`

Change it to a string:

`as.numeric(df)`

Comment: Hi, this is one step closer! now i do get a vector, but now each time the row ended in the data frame, there is an NA symbol (i took out what = "character") I think there might be extra spaces in the data, how do i solve that?

Comment: Using `what="numeric"` returns a character vector as the type of `what` is "character"` - you want `scan(text="0 1 0 1", what=numeric())`

Answer (score 0):

I cut and paste your example into a text file called "test" and was able to import your example using this code here:

```
testdf = read.csv('test', sep=" ", header = FALSE)
```

When I first tried, I just got a bunch of columns with no data.

For me, the key was the term:

```
header = False
```

Hope this helps!